# Steam does not start, various errors and warnings involved

Tags: steam

I was running Steam fine and I got an update of the client. After I applied it, Steam was not starting any more and I get these warnings and errors:

```
axel@Desktop-Axel-Ubuntu:~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 13.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1379035603_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1379035603_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1379035603_client)
unlinked 0 orphaned pipes
removing stale semaphore last operated on by process 21580 with name 0eBlobRegistryMutex_DEDFD5AF95D03C2232C7707E9714D78F
removing stale semaphore last operated on by process 21580 with name 0eBlobRegistrySignal_DEDFD5AF95D03C2232C7707E9714D78F
removing stale semaphore last operated on by process 21580 with name 0emSteamEngineInstance
removing stale semaphore last operated on by process 21580 with name 0eSteamEngineLock
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"

(steam:22158): Gtk-WARNING **: Impossible de trouver le moteur de thème dans module_path : « adwaita »

(steam:22158): Gtk-WARNING **: Impossible de trouver le moteur de thème dans module_path : « adwaita »
/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:1137: error: unexpected identifier `direction', expected character `}'
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1379035603_client)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
[0914/113555:WARNING:proxy_service.cc(958)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
```

I have ia32-libs installed and running 3.8.0-30-generic x86_64.

Comment: This : '/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:1137: error: unexpected identifier `direction', expected character `}'' looks like a compiler error.

Comment: I could only fix mine with a complete reinstall of steam. so i went: sudo apt-get remove steam* then went in ~/.steam and deleted everything there. then install it again sudo apt-get install steam

Answer (score 1):

Solution given by OP:

> I went to Valve's Github issues tracker and someone advised to delete
>   the `~/.steam/steam/appcache` folder. I did and Steam now works fine.